# How does fread work?

Tags: c++, matlab, fread

I understand that in various programming languages, such as MatLab and C++, fread is used as a way to read in a binary file. I was wondering how exactly this worked? In particular, how does fread know there is a new number being read in from the binary file; is there a delimiter of some kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard C library function `fread` attempts to read a certain number of "objects" from a file, and returns how many it was able to read successfully. It is a wrapper to the system call `read` (also part of the standard C library) which attempts to read a certain number of *bytes* from a file, and returns how many it was able to read successfully. The system call is implemented by the operating system, specifically by the filesystem.

While the exact implementation details could be complicated (due to the existence of buffers, from example), at heart this is really simple: the filesystem knows how long a file is, and stores its current offset (position) in the file (this is actually part of the *file descriptor*, several of which could refer to the same file).